# FileCopy in Access with wildcards

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having a heck of a time with something that I think should be so very simple. I think age is getting to me.

All I want to do is in access, run a command that would mimic the following DOS command:

```
copy c:\1\ABC123-*.txt c:\1\ABC456-*.txt
```

It seems that filecopy does not support wildcards and for the life of me fso.copyfile just wont work (probably because I am dense). I have also tried to use the copy command using shell and cant get that to work.

To be a little clearer:

The database keeps track of parcels of land. These are "owned" by a land company. On occasion, these parcels are sold from one land company to another. When that happens we have to keep the old records and the new, so the parcel is "copied" to the new land company complete with all its payment history, etc. There are physical documents attached to that record too, and these must appear in BOTH places. I need to copy those PDF files from one parcel number to another (I already have code that duplicates the document entries in the database, I just need to fix the physical files).

So, as an example, parcel 1234 may have a deed, a latenotice, and a survey. Those files would exist as something like 1234-deed.pdf, 1234-latenotice.pdf, and 1234-survey.pdf. I need those files copied to 5678-deed.pdf, 5678-latenotice.pdf, and 5678-survey.pdf after the rest of the database copy code runs.

I need something simple, it only needs to run in that one part of the database so I do not need it to be extensible, or to create a new function, or whatever.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no single VBA and/or FSO command that duplicates `copy`'s "mass copy and rename" functionality. You can either call `copy` directly or write a loop that enumerates all files in the directory, checks the prefix, creates a new file name with 123 replaced by 456 and then copies the file. (BTW, if it's for one-time use, why not use your copy command directly in a cmd window instead of solving that problem with VBA?)

Comment: I might not should have said "one time". To be specific, there is a single part of the database where the user can copy records. This duplicates all the records under a new number. I need this to run at that point. I do not need to use it anywhere else in the system. It does not need to be extensible, callable, extendable, etc etc. I have tried calling copy directly using the shell command and that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

Give this a try:

```
    Dim F As File
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    
    FromPath = "C:\1"
    ToPath = "C:\1"

    Debug.Print FSO.GetFolder(FromPath).Files.Count

    For Each F In FSO.GetFolder(FromPath).Files
        If Instr(F.Name,"ABC123-") Then
            FileCopy FromPath & "\" & F.Name, ToPath & "\" & Replace(F.Name, "123", "456")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: SWEET! At first I tried the original version you posted and got confused really fast :-) This version works excellently. Thank you!

Comment: You added some new text which changed the parameters of your original question...  Therefore, I had to adjust the answer.  Glad to be of help!